# Why is the definition of coprime/comaximal ideals $I + J = R$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, definition

Two questions

Let $R$ be commutative and have $1_R$. Two ideals are called coprime/comaxmal if $I + J = R$

(1) the above is equivalent to saying there exists $i + j = 1_R$. But to me, this condition should be definition and everywhere (i.e. Chinese Reminder) I look, they use the element condition, never $I + J = R$. So why don't we just say coprime/comaximal if $i + j = 1_R$?

(2) I understand why it is called co-prime, but what does co-maximal even mean? Co means together, and what does maximal have to do with this? We aren't on a PID.

Comment: (1) Definitions should be concise and short as you said "I+J=R" is equivalent to " there is $i\in I$ and $j\in J$ such that $i+j=1$". The first is short so, it's good for a definition.

Comment: I've always taken "comaximal" to mean "together, they are as large as possible". But I don't like this because maximal ideal doesn't mean as large as possible. However, that's more of a complaint about the term "maximal ideal" than it is "comaximal".

Comment: @JulianMejia it is like 3 inches longer than saying $I + J = R$, plus this isn't a faithful definition as everyone just boils down to the condition. This surely cannot be the answer.

Comment: “Co-prime” means there is no prime ideal that “divides” both (with ideals, you think of “divisibility” as corresponding to inclusion, because this is exactly what it means in the rings that were the origin of ideal theory, rings of integers in number fields). Similarly, “comaximal” means that no maximal ideal “divides” (that is, contains) both of them. This happens, in rings with unity, if and only if $I+J = R$ (as otherwise, the ideal $I+J$ is contained in a maximal ideal, which therefore contains both $I$ and $J$).

Comment: In rings with unity, and more generally, rings in which $R^2=R$, maximal ideals are always prime ideals. So being “comaximal” (no maximal ideal contains both) is equivalent to being “coprime” (no prime ideal contains both).  In more general rings, you can have maximal ideals that are not prime, and proper ideals that are not contained in maximal ideals, so the notions may diverge there.

Comment: (Do you object to “coprime” in integers? If “co” means together, “coprime” means “primes together”... which means, what, exactly?)

Comment: Let me try to answer each comment. one by one. " “comaximal” means that no maximal ideal “divides” (that is, contains) both of them.".

So basically you are saying they are "maximal together", hence co-maximal. For if $I \subset Z$ and $J \subset Z$, then $I + J \subset Z$, but this means $Z = I + J = R$, hence they are (co)-maximal in $R$. So no such maximal $Z$ exists and in the ring with $1_R$, if $Z$ were prime, it would not exist either, hence co-prime. I do not know much about Boolean rings (that's what you meant by $R^2 = R$ right?).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin No I do not object coprime in integers. According to wikipedia, it is just another way of saying relatively prime. But in this case if the ideals are "relatively prime", then there exists $r_1x + r_2y = 1$, but in we are in ideal, so this reduces to $x + y = 1$

Comment: @Hawk: You keep assuming your rings have a $1$; there is no reason to do so if you don’t have to.

Comment: @Hawk: No, $R^2$ has nothing to do with Boolean rings; it is simply the ideal generated by all products of two elements of $R$ (just like the ideal $IJ$ when $I$ and $J$ are ideals; $R$ is an ideal, after all). If $R$ has a $1$, this is trivially $R$, but you can have it equal $R$ even in other cases (e.g., continuous functions of compact support form a ring without a one, but in which $R^2=R$).

Comment: The only reason I am assuming it is because when Dummit/Foote introduces the definition, it says we are to assume all rings are commutative and have $1_R$. Hence I thought it is mandatory (page 265 ref)

Comment: If it were, they wouldn’t have to say so explicitly. Rings may or may not have a one, depending on your conventions.

Comment: If our (commutative) ring does not have $1$, how would we (or is this what you are trying to tell me) write $x + y  = 1$ then? On [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_(ring_theory)#Types_of_ideals).

Comment: @Hawk: If it doesn’t have a $1$, you wouldn’t be able to write $x+y=1$; but you could still say “$I+J=R$”.

Comment: But the naming comes from when we have comm ring with $1$ right? And where/when exactly is the condition $I + J = R$ used when $R$ isn't comm and does not contain $1_R$?

Comment: @Hawk: Ring theory and ideal theory, *as a whole*, originated in commutative domains, specifically in rings of integers of number fields. A lot of the ideas are then abstracted from that. The condition $I+J=R$ is used *all the time* because it is (i) equivalent to “$1\in I+J$” when you are in a ring with $1$; but (ii) also sensical when $R$ does *not* have a $1$. *There are lots of rings that don’t have a $1$ and that people work with all the time*. Just because you haven’t run into one at this stage of your education does not mean they don’t exist or that people don’t care about them.

Comment: I wasn't implying that they don't exist, I was simply asking an example (e.g. type of problem) because this elementary concept is introduced when rings are comm and have $1_R$ and the replies so far imply they are quite ubiquitous in nature

Answer (score 1):

You often want your definition to be as general as possible:

> For any ring $R$, we'll say two ideals $I$ and $J$ are **comaximal** if $I+J=R$. In particular, if $R$ is unital with identity $1_R$, then these ideals are comaximal if there exists $i\in I$ and $j \in J$ such that $i+j = 1_R$.

One definition that works for *any* ring is cleaner than having two definitions, one in the case that your ring is unital and one for non-unital rings.

**I made this Community Wiki so someone else can explain why "comaximal" is a good choice of word.**

Comment: In Dummit/Foote, the definition given assumes (at the start of the section) all Rings have $1_R$ and is commutative.

Comment: @Hawk: And since not all rings are commutative in general (say... matrices) then that should signal to you that this is a rather local convention, not a general statement about The Way Things Are(tm).

Comment: So the general definition does not require $1_R$ nor commutativity? So the condition $I + J = R$ taken to be comaximal would mean $x \in I$ and $y \in J$ such that $x + y = r$?

Comment: @Hawk you need some "for all" and "there exist" quantifiers, but yeah.

Comment: *for all $r \in R$, there exists $x \in I$ and $y \in J$ such that $x + y = r$